# How to parse strings based on user provided format tokens?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to parse information out of a string based on an input string and user defined token placemant (I define the possible tokens). For example:

Input Format: `#artist# - #song# [#id#]`

Input String: `Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]`

I need to correctly pull out the artist, song, and ID.

My current approach is to replace everything outside of the token as a regex literal, then replace the tokens with the appropriate regex group.

```
let format = "#artist# - #song# [#id#]";
let split = format.split(/#\w*#/);

for(let i = 0; i< split.length; i++) {
  if (split[i] !== '') {
    let rep = split[i].split('').map(x => `\\${x}`).join('');
    format = format.replace(split[i], rep);
  }
}
format = format.replace('#artist#', '([\\w\\s]*)').replace('#song#', '([\\w\\s]*)').replaceAll('#ignore#', '([\\w\\s]*)');
let test = new RegExp(format, 'g');
let res = 'Taylor Swift - AntiHero [ID123]'.matchAll(test);
```

The above hard coded example works, but when using the correct song name "Anti-Hero", the hyphen breaks my regex match on `([\w\s]*)`. Also removing the brackets surrounding the ID breaks my results even though it could be a valid format. In this case, the brackets would just become part of the ID.

My approach as a whole seems incorrect as there can be issues in my format replacement (`' '` will match the previous replaced `' - '`), and non word / space characters break the token search that I currently have. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Replace all `[\\w\\s]*` with `.*?`. Note the `[` must be escaped.

Comment: Does https://jsfiddle.net/h8Lgowck/ work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach, though not that generic, *(thus there meanwhile is a 2nd reliable generic one too,)* is as follows:

- Implement a function which creates an extractor function from the passed custom hash-based pattern-string provided by the OP ... `#artist# - #song# [#id#]`.
- Use the created extractor for retrieving values from a string which matches or relates to the hash-based pattern-string ... `'Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]'`

As for the **creation part** one has to ...

1. ... create partials from a custom pattern of the form ... `#artist# - #song# [#id#]` ... where `#` are delimiters for keys like `artist`, `song` and `id`, as well as the later to be used splitting [regex-alternation](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) parts like `-`,  `[` and `]`.

   One does achieve this by [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting the pattern via following regex ... [/#([^#]+)#/g](https://regex101.com/r/Vvdh0X/1) ... and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)ing the result which produces following `partial` array ...

   ```
   ['artist', ' - ', 'song', ' [', 'id', ']']
   ```
2. ... separate the partials into `keys` and the partials in between those keys where the latter become part of a later to be used regex `alternation`.

   This is done by a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) task which, depending on the current array index' oddness / evenness, does `push` the currently processed `partial` item into either the `keys` or the `alternatives` array which produces following result ...

   ```
   { keys: ['artist', 'song', 'id'], alternatives: [' - ', ' [', ']'] }
   ```
3. ... create a regex which features an alternation pattern by mapping each alternative partial where one does escape each regex specific control character and each possible whitespace sequence which finally get joined by a regex-OR and passed to the regex creation.

   [The result of this task is the following `regXExtractor`](https://regex101.com/r/Vvdh0X/2) ...

   ```
   /\s+\-\s+|\s+\[|\]/g
   ```
4. ... finally create and return the extractor function which on one hand does execute the splitting of a source string like ... `'Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]'` ... into the values as intended / described by the hashed pattern string ( `#artist# - #song# [#id#]` ) and on the other hand creates an object of key-value pairs by reducing the before created `keys` array and assigning each key's related value.

   The result of invoking the created and returned `extractor` function by passing e.g. `'Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]'` to it will be ...

   ```
   { artist: 'Taylor Swift', song: 'Anti-Hero', id: 'ID123' }
   ```

Implemented approach and proof of concept for solving a task like described by the OP.

*One also should notice how forgiving the approach and its generated extractor pattern(s) will handle additional whitespace in case it was provided for value separation of the hash-based pattern-string* ...

```js
function createExtractorFromHashedPattern(pattern) {
  // creates partials from a custom pattern of the form
  // ... '#artist# - #song# [#id#]' ... where '#' are
  // delimiters for keys like `artist`, `song` and `id`,
  // as well as the later to be used splitting regex
  // alternation parts like ' - ', ' [' and ']'.
  const partials = String(pattern)
    // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/Vvdh0X/1]
    .split(/#([^#]+)#/g)
    .slice(1);

  // separate the partials into keys and the partials
  // in between those keys where the latter become part
  // of a later to be used regex alternation.
  const { keys, alternatives } = partials
    .reduce((result, partial, idx) => {

      result[
        (idx % 2)
          && 'alternatives'
          || 'keys'
      ].push(partial);

      return result;

    }, { keys: [], alternatives: [] });

  // create a regex alternation pattern by ...
  const alternation = alternatives
    // ... mapping each alternative partial ...
    .map(alternative =>
      // ... where one does escape ...
      alternative
        // ... each regex specific control character ...
        .replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
        // ... and each possible whitespace sequence ...
        .replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+')
    )
    // which finally get joined by a regex-OR.
    .join('|');

  // create the extracting regex
  // from the `alternation` pattern.
  const regXExtractor = RegExp(alternation, 'g');

  // returns the extractor function ...
  return function extractor (source) {
    // ... which on one hand does execute the splitting
    // of a source string into the values as intended/
    // described by the hashed pattern string ...
    const extractedValues = String(source)
      // see ... e.g. [https://regex101.com/r/Vvdh0X/2]
      .split(regXExtractor);

    // ... and on the other hand creates an object of
    // key-value pairs by reducing the before created
    // `keys` and assigning each key's related value.
    return keys
      .reduce((result, key, idx) =>
        Object.assign(result, {
          [ key ]: extractedValues[idx],
        }), {}
      );
  }
}

const extractor = 
  createExtractorFromHashedPattern('#artist# - #song# [#id#]');

const {
  artist,
  song,
  id,
} = extractor('Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]');

console.log(
  'extracted values each by its key ...',
  { artist, song, id },
);

const extractedValues = Object
  .values(
    // NOTICE how the pattern forgives additional whitespace.

    extractor('Taylor Swift   -   Anti-Hero    [ID123]')
  );
console.log(
  'extracted values as array of values ...',
  extractedValues,
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Edit**

Another, even more reliable, approach was to directly transform the provided input format into a regex which features [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups).

The input format string of ...

```
'#artist# - #song# [#id#]'
```

... then stepwise changes into ...

```
'(?<artist>.*?) \\- (?<song>.*?) \\[(?<id>.*?)\\]'
```

... into ...

```
'(?<artist>.*?)\\s+\\-\\s+(?<song>.*?)\\s+\\[(?<id>.*?)\\]'
```

... into [the final regex](https://regex101.com/r/Vvdh0X/3) of ...

```
/(?<artist>.*?)\s+\-\s+(?<song>.*?)\s+\[(?<id>.*?)\]/
```

Due to having to escape possibly existing regex control characters in between the named group patterns one can not create such a regex pattern and the regex itself at once via a single regex based `replace` task.

But one could do so by again `split`ting and `slice`ing the passed input format where one then would `map` each partial / token according to its evenness / oddness and finally `join` the array into the above provided final pattern ...

```js
const partials = '#artist# - #song# - #id#'
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/Vvdh0X/1]
  .split(/#([^#]+)#/g)
  .slice(1);

const pattern = partials
  .map((partial, idx, arr) =>
    (idx % 2 === 0)
      && (
        (arr[idx + 1] === '')
          && `(?<${ partial }>.*)`
          || `(?<${ partial }>.*?)`
      ) || partial
        .replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
        .replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+')
  )
  .join('');

const regXExtractor = RegExp(pattern);

console.log({
  inputForm: '#artist# - #song# - #id#',
  partials,
  pattern,
  regXExtractor,
});

console.log({
  inputForm: '#artist# - #song# [#id#]',
  regXExtractor: RegExp(
    '#artist# - #song# [#id#]'
      .split(/#([^#]+)#/g)
      .slice(1)
      .map((partial, idx, arr) =>
        (idx % 2 === 0)
          && (
            (arr[idx + 1] === '')
              && `(?<${ partial }>.*)`
              || `(?<${ partial }>.*?)`
          ) || partial
            .replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
            .replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+')
      )
      .join('')
  ),
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The final solution then implements a function which creates from the provided input format the extracting regex as just shown with the above example code. The returned regex can be directly matched against any input string which relates to the before provided input format ...

```js
function createRegexFromHashedPattern(pattern) {
  return RegExp(
    String(pattern)
      .split(/#([^#]+)#/g)
      .slice(1)
      .map((partial, idx, arr) =>
        (idx % 2 === 0)
          && (
            (arr[idx + 1] === '')
              && `(?<${ partial }>.*)`
              || `(?<${ partial }>.*?)`
          ) || partial
            .replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
            .replace(/\s+/g, '\\s+')
      )
      .join('')
  );
}

const regXExtractor = 
  createRegexFromHashedPattern('#artist# - #song# [#id#]');

const {
  artist,
  song,
  id,
} = regXExtractor
  .exec('Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]')
  ?.groups ?? {};

console.log(
  'extracted values each by its key ...',

  { artist, song, id },
);
console.log('\n');

console.log(
  'extracted values as `group`-result ...',

  createRegexFromHashedPattern('#artist# - #song# - #id#')
    .exec('Taylor Swift   -   Anti-Hero   -   ID123')
    ?.groups ?? {}
);
console.log(
  'extracted values as `slice`d `match`es array ...',

  'Taylor Swift :: Anti-Hero :: ID123'
    .match(
      createRegexFromHashedPattern('#artist# :: #song# :: #id#')
    )
    .slice(1)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works great for the given format example of `#artist# - #song# [#id#]`, but fails for other valid formats such as `#artist# - #song# - #id#` and given 'Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero - ID123'. I thought maybe the hyphen in the song name was causing issues, but doesn't work correctly even without it.

Comment: @Tristan … I did already implement a second approach which can process any provided input format. I'll post it as soon as I come up with an explanation of it. Meanwhile the OP might post even more test cases.

Comment: @Tristan ... The implementation of the 2nd, finally generic and reliable approach has been provided.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this. The following function will take in an input format and string and output an object containing entries such as `"song": "Anti-Hero"` and `"id": "ID123"`.

```
function extract(format, string) {
  // Get a list of the parts of the input format.
  // The odd entries will be keys like "artist" or
  // "song" and the even ones will be separators
  // that we don't need to store.
  let segments = format.split("#");

  // Create an object to contain key-value pairs
  // such as id: "ID123"
  let output = {};

  // Iterate through all of the segments in the format.
  for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
    // If the current segment is empty, skip it.
    if (segments[i].length == 0) continue;

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      // If the current segment is a separator like " - " or "["
      // skip past it and clip that part of the string.

      if (string.startsWith(segments[i])) {
        string = string.slice(segments[i].length);
      } else {
        throw new Error("String does not match format");
      }
    } else {
      // Find the distance until the next seperator
      let length = 0;
      while (!(segments[i + 1] && string.slice(length).startsWith(segments[i + 1]))
             && length < string.length) {
        length++;
      }

      // Store the key and value in the output object
      // and clip off the beginning of the string.
      output[segments[i]] = string.slice(0, length);
      string = string.slice(length);
    }
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(extract("#artist# - #song# [#id#]",
                    "Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]"));

// Outputs { artist: "Taylor Swift", id: "ID123", song: "Anti-Hero" }
```

Answer (score -1):

In this example you can simply split on a longer string

```
let myString = "Taylor Swift - Anti-Hero [ID123]"
let myParts = myString.split(" - ")
// myParts now an array with "Taylor Swift" and "Anti-Hero [ID123]"
```

It will fail still if you have song names with " - " in the title but hopefully that is more rare! Hope this helps :)

Comment: You misunderstood the question, confusing what is input and what is expected output.